# Most efficient way to search data based on variables from a form

Tags: c#, sql-server, variables

I'm looking for the most efficient way to search data based on a user's entry in a form.  Most likely dropdowns.

Is it more efficient to do this on the front end or the back end?  To be specific, I'm using C# with a SQL Server back end.  For efficiency, is it better to write a stored procedure in SQL Server and pass the variables to that, or is it better to write a "Select * from MyTable where" string and use the variables on the CS page in C#?  There will be multiple variables and not all of them might be used at any given time.

Comment: Depends. If you want to filter a list that you already have in memory at the frontend, then it's probably better done there. If it's a "cold" selection, then in 99.9% of instances, the DB does this the most efficient way.

Comment: You can filter the source query using SQL or Linq, the binding source if supported like with a data table, or use the BindingListView instead of BindingList.

Comment: I would not expect any major difference between a stored procedure and a multiple `.Where` statements. I would expect indices to have a major impact.  But as always with regards to performance, measure!

Answer (score -1):

I always try writing anything that can be done on DB, in the specified packages. It makes it easier to change anything related to my project. Like, if I need to change my select, I don't need to change anything in my code, and later Commit/Push or Change dll in the working environment. I can simply do all the changes on my DB easily.